# ActionListener with ActionListener vs 2 Separate ActionListeners

Tags: java, actionlistener

Is it better to have an embedded ActionListener within another ActionListener or is it better to have them as separate ones? I have JComboBox1, JComboBox2, and JTextField. If a certain value in JComboBox1 is selected, then JComboBox2 will appear and if a certain value in JCombox2 is selected, then JTextField appears, otherwise, they are hidden. Which is more efficient?

Comment: Efficiency should not be your concern here.

Comment: @DaveNewton Not concerning efficiency, which approach is better.

Comment: @dalawh: your question would be much clearer if you showed us the code of your two alternatives. As is, we have to guess what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a single class implement the Actionlistener interface. Just identify the source of Event in your actionPerformed class and make necassary action.

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
    {
        if(ae.getSource() == combobox1 )
        {
            combobox2.setVisible(true);
        }   
        else if(ae.getSource() == combobox2 )
        {   
            textfield.setVisible(true);
        }

    }
```

Comment: But doing this is generally considered a bad practice. It's cleaner to have only one responsibility per listener.

Comment: @JBNizet Agreed, but I always prefer lesser number of objects in my code. Hence I prefer to group common events to be handled within a single objects

Comment: So you agree that it would be cleaner to have separate listeners, but you keep using and recommending a single one? Where's the logic?

Comment: @JBNizet I meant there is no one right answer in these sorts. Its just developer perference.

Comment: I am getting the sense that using 2 separate listeners is better from what JB Nizet is saying.

Comment: Here it looks like two instances of the same object, taking a parameter of the widget to set visible.